# Appending a textarea text field on Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, textarea

Is there a spark TextArea decleration in actionscript3 file since private var ta:TextArea is a mx component?

Comment: "since private var ta:TextArea is a mx component"? What's that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:TextArea id="textArea">This is a spark TextArea component</s:TextArea>

</s:Application>
```

or:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.components.TextArea;

        private var _textArea:TextArea;

        private function init(e:FlexEvent):void
        {
            _textArea = new TextArea();
            _textArea.text = "This is a spark TextArea component";
            addElement(_textArea);

        }// end function

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```